# Colorful term for someone with a long-overdue library book

Tags: phrase-requests, humor

I'm trying to find a humorous term for someone who still has an overdue library book after a number of years. I first came up with "delinquent lendee", but I'm sure there's something more apropos or alliterative.

Comment: Why beat around the bush? Call them what they are; a petty thief.

Comment: Personally I'd call them a "dead-tree deadbeat."

Comment: @TomO'Connor: such, uh, long-term borrowings are rarely *intentional* in my experience, so *thief* doesn't seem to apply. Plus, overdue fines are a good source of library income if/when they are collected, so such people are really benefactors-in-waiting.

Comment: Taserian, you could improve your question by giving us some more criteria to choose the best answer. Do you want to imply mild or severe disapproval? Is humor the most important consideration, or is transparency (i.e. the ability to convey the intended meaning without extensive context)? Etc. etc. Right now, this question is in danger of being closed as "not constructive", because there is really no objective way to choose a best answer.

Comment: This cartoon seemed appropriate: http://www.smbc-comics.com/index.php?db=comics&id=396#comic

Comment: @Marthaª Theft is still theft whether intentional or not.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here are a few I came up with, choose one that suits you:

Book-Bandit

Book-Clip

Book-Plunderer

Book-Pocket

Book-Lifter

Library-Climber

Library-Breaker

Book-Breaker

Biblio-Bandit

Lendup-Artist

Biblio-Bezzler

Biblio-Prowler

Book-Prowler

Comment: Lol -- none of them accounts for a simpleton who just failed to show up. Too bad. :)

Comment: I like *Bilbo-Bandit*. (Biblio Baggins?)

Comment: @muntoo lol. also, Biblio-Hobbit. :D

Answer (score 41):

How about ... **tome raider**?

Or **book keeper** (not to be confused with *bookkeeper*)

Comment: I like tome raider a lot, I'll be using it.

Comment: "There is one thing you should learn/When there is no one else to turn to/Call...for English Chicken! (_cluck, cluck, cluck, cluck_)/Call...for English Chicken! (_cluck, awk!_)" (with apologies to [Super Chicken](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Chicken) )

Comment: Haha, thanks, @Gnawme... I know what my avatar is going to be now.

Comment: I'd like to chime in that while I do also like *tome raider*, my upvote is mainly for *book keeper*, which I find deliciously wry.

Answer (score 23):

Assuming they have no intention of actually returning the books, you might call them [biblioklepts](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/biblioklept).

Comment: Biblioklepts! I like the word, myself, but I'm not sure if my audience would get the idea directly.

Comment: @taserian You work at a library no? A library should encourage learning. If you've got it in you, encourage them to look it up. **Use this one**

Comment: I don't work at a library; this was used in a Toastmasters speech. . .

Answer (score 11):

- tome hoarder
- book miser
- deadbeat borrower
- literary liberator
- slow reader
- library annex (particularly if they have a number of books)
- library benefactor (due to overdue charges)

Comment: I literally (dare I say it?) laughed out loud at *slow reader.*

Comment: Yes, *slow reader* is excellent!... if provided sufficient context.  The other (also very good) choices on this list are less dependent on knowing beforehand that we're talking about severely overdue library books.  Indeed, for many of them we can figure out the context from the term itself.

Answer (score 8):

- reference renegade
- dewey decimal delinquent
- archive absconder
- folio fugitive
- overdue outlaw
- circumforaneous card catalog crook
- hard cover criminal
- "his library card was his mugshot"
- the unshushable

Comment: That's a lot of alliteration.

Comment: @Caleb - Alliteration is mentioned by the OP, but yes, it is.

Comment: I loved this, but "Dewey decimal delinquent" and "archive absconder" ruined my ability to breathe, since I was laughing so loud!

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps [scofflaw](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/scofflaw) could be appropriated for this use.  It's probably what I would say in the same situation, off the top of my head.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the accepted term is "delinquent borrower", but that's not very colorful.

Answer (score 4):

Someone who has borrowed and kept a library book for such a long time that the book is now ancient history could be called a *[biblionecrophile](http://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=necrophile)*.

If they haven't returned the book because they suffer from an obsession with hoarding books, then they're a *[bibliomaniac](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bibliomania)*.

Comment: perhaps you meant `lignonecrophile` or `necrolignophile` for someone obsessed with dead treas?

Answer (score 3):

How about using "The Loan Ranger"

Answer (score 0):

(Just checked to make sure you're an American over 30)

How about [Costanza](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Library_%28Seinfeld%29) or even "Can't Stands Ya".

Answer (score 0):

AWOR: Absent WithOut Renewal.
Easy to remember.

[a la AWOL: Absent WithOut Leave].